# Python Dictionary Pop

Tags: python, dictionary

My code below opens a csv and puts it into a dictionaries with the columns being lists.  There are duplicate keys and that cannot change.  The key is the account number column which is row[1].  Right now if the 'CITY' string is found in row[8], that key and value will be deleted.  How do I write this so that all other instances of that same key (and the respective values) will also be deleted?

```
with open('c:\\file.csv', 'rb') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        key = row[1]
        result[key].append([row[0], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12]])

        if 'CITY' in row[8]:
            result.pop(key)
```

Here is an input example:

```
3929, 56794, 5555551212, August, IL, 62305, Steve, Johnson, City, Max, Folder, 22, 56
3929, 56794, 5555551212, August, IL, 62305, Steve, Johnson, None, Max, Folder, 22, 85
3929, 58586, 5555551212, August, IL, 62305, Steve, Johnson, None, Max, Folder, 22, 69
```

Here is the output I would like:

```
3929, 58586, 5555551212, August, IL, 62305, Steve, Johnson, None, Max, Folder, 22, 69
```

So since "City" is found in the first row, both of the rows with the 56794 account number will be removed.

Comment: There is no such thing as a dictionary with "duplicate keys".  If you don't want that particular row to be included, why don't you just do that `if` test earlier, and not do the append if CITY is present?

Comment: Sorry, each row in the csv becomes a dictionary.  Then, some of the keys from the several dictionaries are duplicates.  If I do the "if" test earlier, it will only get rid of the row that contains the 'CITY' string.  I need to get rid of that row, and all other rows that then contain that same account number.

Comment: Your code doesn't show each row becoming a dictionary.  It shows one dictionary, with one element from each row being used as a key, and all entries with that key accumulating into a list.  Your code will indeed remove all items that share that key, but if there are other later rows with that key, they won't be "removed" because they aren't there yet at the time you remove them.  It would be helpful if you could include sample data with expected output.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me.  I put the sample data up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a key to be removed if any of its rows contains "CITY" in position 8.  In that case, I think you might be better off keeping track of these "unwanted" keys separately, something like this:

```
with open('c:\\file.csv', 'rb') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    unwantedKeys = set()
    for row in reader:
        key = row[1]
        if 'CITY' in row[8]:
            unwantedKeys.add(key)
            if key in result:
                result.pop(key)
        if key not in unwantedKeys:
            result[key].append([row[0], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12]])
```

The idea is to maintain a list (or, in this example, a set) of keys you want to exclude.  If you encounter a new key that you want to exclude, add it to the set and remove matching results, if any.  If you encounter a row whose key is in the exclude set, you just don't add that row to the results at all.